# Share C# class and static variables in VB.NET insde the same solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution

I want to share code from a C# project inside a VB.Net project.
I want to refer a public class and its variables inside VB.
So I've put both VB and C# project inside the same solution.
Here is the declaration of C# class insde C# project:

```
public class MyUtils
{

    public static byte[] zeroArray = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    ....
```

When I want to refer it inside VB I will have below errors:
'MyUtils' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

I have change the accessibility of every object to `public` in C# but I don't know how to allow access to C# class. I should add that I have not enough familiarity with VB and its inheritance mechanisms.

Comment: Not familiar with VB.net but am aware that c#/vb can share code a quick google showed [this](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/calling-a-c-dll-from-vb.net.htm)

Comment: It *is* possibly to have a solution with C# and VB projects. I have worked with an example,  but cannot access it anymore

Comment: `Friend` in vb.net is the same as `internal` in C#.  So the snippet you posted does not match the error message at all.  The C# assembly you actually used did not yet have `public` in the class definition.  Do make sure that the vb.net and C# projects belong to the same solution and that the vb.net project uses a project reference instead of a file reference to avoid such mishaps.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know why it happened. My C# project was change to a class Library and I referenced it in VB.NET project. But the error was as above. When I changed the VB.NET project to reference `dll` file of C# project it work without any problems!

Answer (score 1):

I created a C# console app named "ConsoleApp2" using .NET Framework 4.8 and added a class named "MyUtils":

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class MyUtils
    {
        public static byte[] zeroArray = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    }
}
```

I built the project to make sure that worked.

Then I added a VB.NET console app project named "ConsoleApp1" to the same solution. I added a reference to the ConsoleApp2 project:

[image: Add reference dialog]

and used this code:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim bb = ConsoleApp2.MyUtils.zeroArray
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", bb.Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2"))))
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

and ran it to get the output:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00